# Thunderbird plugin to get addressbook/contacts in synch with Tine 2.0

Tags: thunderbird, carddav, contact-manager

I'm looking for a Thunderbird plugin which allows me to make usage of [Tine2.0](https://www.tine20.org) (Groupware, CRM) adressbook cardDAV interface.

Any hints?

Answer (score 1):

The [Cardbook addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/cardbook/?src=hp-dl-upandcoming) completely replaces Thunderbird's built-in address book and provides support for CardDAV.

I have not tried it with Tine but it seems to work well with my Radicale server. Assuming both Tine and Cardbook stick to the standard, they should work together. Setup includes a URL to your contact file(s), username and password.

*Nota bene:* If you use HTTPS with a server that does not have a valid certificate (in particular a self-signed one) you need to add an exception for that server in Thunderbird's certificate configuration dialogue first.